# Assign attribute id for p tag it's not working

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get id names from a array and trying to assign id names to each p tag which are append dynamically when i click the button, html is:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <button id="button">Add new div</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script is :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#button').click(function(){ 
        var data = [{'id':'user1'},{'id':'user2'},{'id':'user3'},{'id':'user4'},{'id':'user5'},];
        $.each(data, function(val) { 
            var light=$('<p></p>'); 
            light.attr('id',+val.id); 
            light.text('one'); 
            $("#container").append(light);
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

[code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Hppfg/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var data = [{'id':'user1'},{'id':'user2'},{'id':'user3'},{'id':'user4'},{'id':'user5'},];
        $.each(data, function(i, val) { // added index parameter
            var light=$('<p></p>');
            light.attr('id', val.id);   // removed '+'
            light.text('one');

            $("#container").append(light);
        });
    });
});
```

Also see the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hppfg/12/).

=== UPDATE ===

```
var data = [{'id':'user1'},{'id':'user2'},{'id':'user3'},{'id':'user4'},{'id':'user5'},];
var position = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var light=$('<p></p>')
            .attr('id', data[position].id)
            .text('one');
        $("#container").append(light);
        position++;
        position %= data.length;
    });
});
```

Also see my [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hppfg/16/).

Comment: i try this code it's working fine help me to add that p tag one by one when i click the button

Comment: woh very nice thanks, i want this only again thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

You were using first param of the `each` callback whitch is index, second param is value itself.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('#button').click(function(){
          var data = [{'id':'user1'},{'id':'user2'},{'id':'user3'},{'id':'user4'},{'id':'user5'}];
          $.each(data, function(index, value) {            

          var light=$('<p></p>');
          light.attr('id', index);
          light.text(value.id);       
          $("#container").append(light);
          });  
  });
});
```

Here is working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Hppfg/8/

**update**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('#button').click(function(){
          var data = [{'id':'user1'},{'id':'user2'},{'id':'user3'},{'id':'user4'},{'id':'user5'}];
          $.each(data, function(index, value) {            

              $('<p></p>', {
                  id : index,
                  text: value.id
              }).appendTo("#container");

          });  
  });
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hppfg/15/

Comment: is there way to add that p tag one by one when i click the button

Comment: Yup, it's pretty good. But I just simplified a little bit. See update.

Answer (score 0):

remove the plus(+) before +val.id

add another parameter in the each callback, first param is the index, 2nd is the value;

```
$.each(data, function(index,val) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: you have to update the $.each to  $.each(data, function(index,val) ... you are actually using the index of every item, that is why that id value is always NaN

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
  $.each(data, function(val,value) {            
      var light=$('<p></p>');
      light.attr('id',+value.id);
      light.text('one');
```

Comment: i tried it's working fine help me to add that p tag one by one when i click the button